# Spark reducebykey returns y

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset

```
1, india, delhi
2, chaina, bejing
3, russia, mosco
2, england, London
```

When I perform

```
df.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0).toInt, rec))
  .reduceByKey((x,y)=> y)
  .map(rec => rec._2)
  .foreach {println }
```

Above code is returning below output. Usually `reducebykey` works as accumulated value and current value to sum values of same key, but here how it is working internally. What value x and what value y. And how it is returning y

```
1, india, delhi
2, chaina, bejing
3, russia, mosco
```

Comment: Maybe you can put `.foreach {println }` after `reduceByKey` and see what it produced...?

Comment: It is producing. 1, 1, india, delhi
2, 2, chaina, bejing
3, 3, russia, mosco.

Comment: Are you trying to get the last record of any given id? I'm not sure that `.reduceByKey()` has a guaranteed order during processing, so this code would be non-deterministic.

Comment: You would have to give each record an ephemeral unique id, in it's found order, and then `.groupByKey()` on the first element of each record, ordering (descending) on the unique id, then selecting the first of each group.

Comment: What is the output that you expect ?

Comment: Here it removes duplicate keys how reducebykey works internally I am looking for that

Comment: is it a df or a rdd? what spark version are you using? I dont think we've reduceByKey in spark 2.0 on df's. you will probably have to to groupByKey and then reduce

Answer (score 2):

Re:"What value x and what value y", you can print to see their values. Make sure you check the executor logs and not driver to see this print statement. Moreover run it multiple times to see if they yield same values for x and y everytime. I do not think the order to read the records is guaranteed. It may not be evident with 4 records you are testing with above.

`df.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0).toInt, rec))
  .reduceByKey((x,y)=> {println(s"x:$x,y:$y");y})
  .map(rec => rec._2)
  .foreach {println }`

Re:"how it is working internally"
reduceByKey merges values for a Key based on the given function. This function is first run locally on each partition. The output for each partition is then shuffled based on the keys and then another reduce operation happens. This is similar to combiner function in Map-reduce. This helps in less amount of data needed to shuffle.
Generally this is used in place of groupByKey(), which results in shuffling at the beginning and then you get a chance to work on the values for the keys.

Attaching couple of pictures here to demonstrate this.

- reduceByKey

[image: reduceByKey]

- groupByKey

[image: groupByKey]